# R - How to show points labels when plotting a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, label

I have a simple matrix that I want to plot (X=Comp.1, Y=Comp2.). But each point has a label that I want to be shown on the plot. Here's the matrix:

```
        Comp.1   Comp.2
M.P.S.  0.18257  0.94809      
P.C.   -0.50166  0.27745 
Voc.   -0.55450  0.05681        
Arith.  0.63838 -0.12874
```

Here's my code:

```
plot(myloadings,pch=16,col='blue',xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-1,1))
abline(v=0)
abline(h=0)
```

What should I add to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the help page for `?text` : text draws the strings given in the vector labels at the coordinates given by x and y. y may be missing since xy.coords(x, y) is used for construction of the coordinates.

Your data:

```
myloadings= data.frame(Comp.1= c(0.18, -0.5, -.55, 0.6), 
                       Comp.2=c(0.95, 0.22,0.06, -0.13))
rownames(myloadings)=c("MPS", "PC", "Voc", "Arith")
```

Your code:

```
plot(myloadings,pch=16,col='blue',xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-1,1))
abline(v=0)
abline(h=0)
```

Plus text labels:

```
text(myloadings, labels=rownames(myloadings), adj=2)
```

[image: plot with text labels]